# HeapBufferStorage memory leak while initialing my object

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I have a view model `MyModelView` with an initializer like this:

```
public init(myModel: MyModel) {
    self.myModel = myModel

    amountText = String(myModel.amount) // Double
    descriptionText = myModel.description
    numberText = "\(myModel.number)" // Double
    weightText = "\(myModel.weight)" // Double
}
```

When I use the new debug memory graph in Xcode 8, I can see the following:

[image: Memory leak]

The backtrace of the first memory leak points to the line `amountText = String(myModel.amount) // Double`. The 2 other ones pointing to `numberText = "\(myModel.number)" // Double` & `weightText = "\(myModel.weight)" // Double`

I just don't understand what's the problem here. Converting a Double into a String using either `"\(Double)"` or `String(Double)` creates a memory leak? Or is it doing it in an initializer? Then why?

Comment: Did you handle this leak?